# Can an elastic search index template define a default type for fields, and allow overriding specific fields only?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am mapping all fields in passed documents, but occasionally elastic search's dynamic field mapping type detection chooses a very restrictive type (like `long`) for a field that contains plain text. This appears to be based on the initial document received by ES containing the field. For example:

Document 1:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": "foo",
  "c": {
    "nested": 5.5
  }
}
```

Document 2:

```
{
  "a": "plain text",
  "b": "bar",
  "c": {
    "nested": "plain text again"
  }
}
```

Can I define an index template such that all values are indexed as `text` by default, and only indexed as other types if I explicitly want to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch allows to customize the dynamic mapping rules. 
For example, you can define a rule which maps `long` to `text`:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "long_to_text": {
          "match_mapping_type": "long",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

More details can be found in the docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html

Comment: I found the dynamic template's path match options very helpful, thanks.